# How to copy table from Word to Excel while preserving formatting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've been coding VBA for many years but this one is a real head-scratcher.

**The task is simple** - Copy data from a table from Microsoft Word to Microsoft Excel.

**The challenge:** Maintain the formatting of the data from Word, which includes bulleted lists and multiple paragraphs. More specifically, I need to include all that formatted text from a cell from the Word table inside a single cell in the corresponding Excel table.

Solutions I've already tried and specifically where I got stuck:

---

**METHOD 01:** Select the entire table in Word, select a single cell in Excel, and paste.

```
Sub Method01_CopyAndPaste()

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
Documents(1).ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

**PROBLEM WITH METHOD 01:** Excel creates multiple rows and merged cells whenever there are multiple paragraphs in the Word Table.

---

**METHOD 02:** Loop through the Word table, and assign all the contents to a Array (variant). Then loop through the Excel table and assign the values from the Array into the table.

```
Sub Method02_Array()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim AryTblData(1 To 10, 1 To 10) As Variant

'Loop through the 10x10 Source table and assign all values to 2 dimensional array
For r = 1 To 10
    For c = 1 To 10
        AryTblData(r, c) = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(r + 1, c)
    Next c
Next r

'Paste the array values into the activesheet starting at cell(1,1)
For r = 1 To 10
    For c = 1 To 10
        Cells(r, c) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(AryTblData(r, c))
    Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

PROBLEM WITH METHOD 02: The formatting is not preserved. Specifically, the bullet points do not appear in the Excel table.

---

**METHOD 03:** Use Application.Sendkeys to simulate the process of manually going to one cell of the Word table, copying it, going to the corresponding cell in the Excel table, pasting it, pressing {TAB} to go to the next cell, and then repeating this process for the total number of cells in the table.

```
Sub Method03_Sendkeys()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

'Loop through the 3x3 Source table and simulate sending keys to copy and paste, cell by cell
For r = 1 To 3
    For c = 1 To 3

        'Activate Microsoft Word window
        AppActivate ("word"), True

        'Select the appropriate cell in the Word table (based on the For Loop)
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(r, c).Select

        'In Word, copy the selection
        Application.SendKeys "^c", True

        'Activate Microsoft Excel window
            'Note: I'm not sure why AppActivate ("excel") does not work, but
            'for some reason Application.caption works for me.
        AppActivate Application.Caption, True

        'Select the appropriate cell in the active Excel worksheet (based on the For Loop)
        Cells(r, c).Select

        'In Excel, edit cell contents
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}", True

        'In Excel, Paste
        Application.SendKeys "^v", True

        'In Excel, Save changes to cell and move 1 cell to the right
        Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True

    Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

**PROBLEM WITH METHOD 03:** It works with only 1 cell, but as soon as I attempt to get more than one cell copied and pasted over, the result is the same data over and over again across multiple cells.

---

**QUESTION:** Is this task even possible to achieve in VBA? I'd love to find a simple and elegant solution, but at this point I would settle for something that WORKS.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Haven't had an extensive read but just a quick search. Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38666154/9758194) help you out?

Comment: Method 2 is on the right track. However what you should do is store the range value for the items in the word document (i.,e. you will have an array or word.ranges.  Then for each cell in the table you do a word.range.copy and then into the excel cell you paste the formatted text from the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the repsponses @JvdV but unfortunately I've already checked that post and it did not address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, the following might work.  I can't test as I don't have your source data

```
Sub Method02_Array()

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Intege

For r = 1 To 10
    For c = 1 To 10
        ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(r + 1, c).Range.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(r, c).Range.PasteSpecial operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Paste:=xlPasteAll
    Next c
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks the reply @Freeflow but unfortunately I tried this and it didn't seem to work. The result was a series of pasted pictures in my Excel spreadsheet. I think I may have found a workaround solution though. I will post as soon as I have a chance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might also try  '.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= 
 False' . This keeps the formatting but puts one paragraph per cell.

Comment: You might be better pasting links from your excel into Word.

Comment: Interesting approach @Freeflow, but I need the paragraphs to stay in the same cell, and not be distributed one paragraph per cell (creating more rows in the spreadsheet). I also need to copy from Word to Excel, and not the other way around. Unless you are suggesting some other workaround for pasting links?

Answer (score 0):

For pasting multiple lines from Word or a pdf into a single cell in Excel - click on the cell, press F2, then paste the text. That keeps it all in one cell. However it does not keep the formatting including colors and strikeouts